# Как поставить пробел в String?

Tags: строки

При выводе String на экран, я получаю : С вас15 .
Как сделать чтоб было : С вас 15 ?

String hz = ("С вас" + vio);

Comment: Это было бы так смешно, если бы не было так грустно `String hz = ("С вас " + vio);`

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.  Я новичек, и первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String hz = ("С вас " + vio);
```

Просто поставить пробел в скобках.

Comment: Но, возможно, это не лучший вариант. Наверное, есть какой-то более быстрый...

Comment: Я завис на ответе, только потом понял насколько всё плохо в вопросе...

Comment: @Other надеюсь, Ваша психика не слишком сильно травмирована)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Мой мир уже никогда не будет прежним!